# cause of ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Users::Confirmations) error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error (`ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Users::Confirmations)`), because the structure connecting view, route, controller, and model is identical to similar method/route used on the same page.

view

```
<%= link_to "Approve", approve_user_path(user), method: :patch %>
```

route

```
as :user do
 patch 'users/:id/approve', to: 'users/confirmations/#approve', as: :approve_user
end
```

controller

```
class Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
 def approve
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.approve
 end
end
```

model

```
class User
 def approve
  self.approved = true
  save
 end
end
```

In comparison, this one works just fine:

view

```
<%= form_for user, url: add_name_path(user) do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_field :firstname %>
 <%= f.text_field :lastname %>
 <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

route

```
patch 'users/:id/add_name', to: 'users/confirmations#add_name', via: :patch, as: :add_name
```

controller

```
class Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
 def add_name
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.update(name_params)
 end

 private
 def name_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :lastname)
 end
end
```

Why does the latter go through, but the former causes an uninitialized constant error for the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `to:` param in your first route has an extra `/` before the method name.

Try this:

`as :user do
 patch 'users/:id/approve', to: 'users/confirmations#approve', as: :approve_user
end`